# Disable microtype warning

Tags: warnings, microtype

My document compiled without warning, I was so proud of it. I updated texlive this morning and suddenly my document produces a warning :(

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \showhyphens  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.
```

How to disable it? I did not update microtype, why does it produce a warning?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

.log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.10.7)  10 OCT 2019 14:29
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2019/02/28 v2.7b Micro-typographical refinements (RS)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
\MT@toks=\toks15
\MT@count=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 790.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen103
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1336.
\MT@listname@count=\count89

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def
File: microtype-pdftex.def 2019/02/28 v2.7b Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)

LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 914.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 914.
\MT@outer@space=\skip43
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2019/02/28 v2.7b microtype main configuration file (RS)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2019-10-02 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2019-10-02 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count90
\l_tmpa_int=\count91
\l_tmpb_int=\count92
\g_tmpa_int=\count93
\g_tmpb_int=\count94
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count95
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count96
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count97
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count98
\c_log_iow=\count99
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count100
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count101
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count102
\l__iow_indent_int=\count103
\c_zero_dim=\dimen104
\c_max_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen106
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen108
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen109
\c_zero_skip=\skip44
\c_max_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip46
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip48
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip49
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count104
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count105
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen110
\g__intarray_font_int=\count106
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count112
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count113
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count114
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count115
\c__kernel_randint_max_int=\count116
\g__fp_array_int=\count117
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count118
\l__sort_length_int=\count119
\l__sort_min_int=\count120
\l__sort_top_int=\count121
\l__sort_max_int=\count122
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count123
\l__sort_block_int=\count124
\l__sort_begin_int=\count125
\l__sort_end_int=\count126
\l__sort_A_int=\count127
\l__sort_B_int=\count128
\l__sort_C_int=\count129
\l__str_internal_int=\count130
\c__str_replacement_char_int=\count131
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count132
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count133
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count134
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count135
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count136
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count137
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count138
\l__regex_balance_int=\count139
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count140
\l__regex_mode_int=\count141
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count142
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count143
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count144
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count145
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count146
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count147
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count148
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count149
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count150
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count151
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count152
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count153
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count154
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count155
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count156
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count157
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count158
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count159
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count160
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count161
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count162
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count163
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count164
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count165
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count166
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count167
\l__regex_step_int=\count168
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count169
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count170
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count171
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count172
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count173
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count174
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count175
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count176
\c_empty_box=\box27
\l_tmpa_box=\box28
\l_tmpb_box=\box29
\g_tmpa_box=\box30
\g_tmpb_box=\box31
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen118
\l__box_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen125
\c_empty_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box39
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen132
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen134
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen135
\g__char_data_ior=\read1

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.def
File: l3deprecation.def 2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2019-04-06 v L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count177
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2019-05-28 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count178
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count179
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count180
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count181
)
Package: lipsum 2019/01/02 v2.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex
File: lipsum.ltd.tex 2019/01/02 v2.2 The Lorem ipsum dummy text
))
(./document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 6.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype)             stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `basictext'.


LaTeX Warning: Command \showhyphens  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of interword spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of character kerning.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman 
(RS)
) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2]
(./document.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12021 strings out of 492166
 234254 string characters out of 6125362
 565125 words of memory out of 5000000
 16385 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 533409 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,4n,67p,208b,317s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (2 pages, 22541 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 9 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 2049 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This warning was introduced after `\showhyphens` was made robust. I already reported this to the maintainer of `microtype` and he said an update is underway. There's not much you can do about this now. You'll have to wait.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Currently there is a pending `microtype` upload on CTAN (https://ctan.org/incoming), so the fix should be out in just a couple of days and your document will be warning-less once again :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks! I can confirm that with the update the problem is solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to silence the warning before the package is updated you can do

```
\documentclass{article}

%

\let\CheckCommand\providecommand
\usepackage{microtype}


\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

`\providecommand` has the same syntax as `\CheckCommand` so will gobble the arguments but always do nothing on an existing command that was being checked.